# How to monitor iphone bandwidth for app testing?

Tags: iphone, applications

I'm testing an iphone app someone has developed for me. It seems that some of the files the app downloads are too large.

Is there an app that monitors the network to allow me how much data my app consumes?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=iphone+bandwidth+monitor. Or better, connect the iPhone to a WiFi router that you control and check the bandwidth there.

Comment: thanks. Those bandwidth monitors are not as detailed, looks like MB is the smallest increment they report on. I'm looking for something that reports kbytes.

Comment: the try to put the iphone behind a router that has can measure the bandwidth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the app uses HTTP(S) to download its file, use [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/). It alows you to follow live all the GET requests done by the app, even when it uses https. It requires Python.

[image]

Instructions on how to use (from the guy who nabbed [Path's addressbook upload](http://mclov.in/2012/02/08/path-uploads-your-entire-address-book-to-their-servers.html)):

1. Download the mitmproxy tool and set it up by going to the folder of mitmproxy and running sudo python setup.py install. If all goes well, mitmproxy must be available in your $PATH.
2. Start mitmproxy by running mitmproxy.
3. Obtain the IP address of your computer by running ifconfig en1 (or whatever is the interface that you are using).
4. Set the proxy on your iPhone by going to your wireless settings, setting
   the proxy to be “Manual”, and set the IP to be your computer’s IP and the port as 8080.

Answer (score 1):

If your developer has given you the source code you could use [Instruments.app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_%28application%29) which can be used to monitor network activity.

1. Open the project in Xcode
2. Select Product->Profile from the menu
3. When Instruments opens select 'Activity Monitor' and then hit record

Comment: sorry, don't have Xcode or the source code, just the app.